# dataframe.get(['param1', 'param2']) returning Nonetype even when the columns actually have the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe called 'merged'.
On running merged.info(), I get

[image: merged.info()]

This is when I print the dataframe.

[image: merged]

All the columns and values in the dataframe are defined and non null.

But the following code, `print(merged.get(['PM2.5_CF1_ug/m3', 'Uptime Minutes', 'RSSI_dbm', 'Temperature_F', 'Humidity_%']))` prints None instead of printing the values.
This is something which is happening suddenly without changing anything in the code. I even tried loading the merged dataframe completely. I am confident that it is a pandas issue but I couldnt find the solution anywhere to this. Please help me resolve this.

Ran the code on google colab
Pandas version: 1.3.5

[image]

Comment: there is a space in UptimeMinutes that shouldn't be there. fix it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in UptimeMinutes. You wrote 'Uptime Minutes' instead

Comment: Please write the actual code of how it should be, rather than just a one liner that points out something

Comment: Thanks a lot, couldn't notice that. I want pandas to throw a column not found error instead of just returning None.